# Cordova compile problem with gradle version 7.5.1

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

When I compile with gradle: `gradle build --warning-mode all --stacktrace`

I obtain many error messages.

Should I downgrade the java version?

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
> Lint infrastructure error
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:116)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.api.ReflectiveLintRunner.runLint(ReflectiveLintRunner.kt:37)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintBaseTask.runLint(LintBaseTask.java:133)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintGlobalTask.doTaskAction(LintGlobalTask.java:37)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalGlobalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:63)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalGlobalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:90)
```

Versions :

```
java -version
java version "18.0.2.1" 2022-08-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing)

cordova -v
11.0.0

cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:
  .gradle broken
  android 10.1.2
  electron 3.1.0
```

gradle properties :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
kotlin.code.style=official
```

gradle-wrapper : `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip`

Comment: When I use gradle command it is running, when I use cordova it changes gradle properties and gradle-wrapper. Help !

Comment: Now I have this error message : `code Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').`

Comment: I add system variable with : CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL :

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip, but I have always error message. Help needed.

Comment: Is this possible to fix org.gradle.jvmargs in config.xml ?

Comment: I add to fix this problem : The :app:processReleaseMainManifest task failed.View task in console log
Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module
 
with org.gradle.jvmargs in platform\android\gradle.properties

[link](https://scans.gradle.com/s/am6kqri4xmnec)

Answer (score 0):

I add system variable with : CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL : services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip

and to fix jvmargs it is necessary to modify :
node_modules\cordova-android\lib\config\GradlePropertiesParser.js with :

```
 _configureProperties (properties) {
        // Iterate though the properties and set only if missing.
        Object.keys(properties).forEach(key => {
            const value = this.gradleFile.get(key);

            if (!value) {
                // Handles the case of adding missing defaults or new properties that are missing.
                events.emit('verbose', `[Gradle Properties] Appending configuration item: ${key}=${properties[key]}`);
                this.gradleFile.set(key, properties[key]);
            } else if (value !== properties[key]) {
                if (this._defaults[key] && this._defaults[key] !== properties[key]) {
                    let shouldEmit = true;
                    if (key === 'org.gradle.jvmargs') {
                        shouldEmit = this._isJVMMemoryLessThanRecommended(properties[key], this._defaults[key]);                        
                    }

                    if (shouldEmit) {
                        // Since the value does not match default, we will notify the discrepancy with Cordova's recommended value.
                        events.emit('info', `[Gradle Properties] Detected Gradle property "${key}" with the value of "${properties[key]}", Cordova's recommended value is "${this._defaults[key]}"`);
                    }
                } else {
                    // When the current value exists but does not match the new value or does matches the default key value, the new value it set.
                    events.emit('verbose', `[Gradle Properties] Updating Gradle property "${key}" with the value of "${properties[key]}"`);
                }

                // We will set the new value in either case.
                 this.gradleFile.set(key, properties[key]);
            }
        });
        //add this line here (Ben) :
        this.gradleFile.set('org.gradle.jvmargs', this.gradleFile.get('org.gradle.jvmargs') + " --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED");
    }
```